# Do nested routes path have a dependency on the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I use ror 3.2 and want to separate controllers that serve administrative purpose in their own folders but using the same model as the public controllers use. I ran into a problem which I will explain here. I came to the problem differently but this explains it better.

Fresh rails app, I run:

```
rails generate scaffold admin/stats name:string value:string
```

among all the other files it creates:

```
create    app/models/admin/stat.rb
```

everything works under:

```
localhost:3000/admin/stats/
```

I see the following routes:

```
 admin_stats GET    /admin/stats(.:format)          admin/stats#index
            POST    /admin/stats(.:format)          admin/stats#create
new_admin_stat GET  /admin/stats/new(.:format)      admin/stats#new
edit_admin_stat GET /admin/stats/:id/edit(.:format) admin/stats#edit
 admin_stat GET     /admin/stats/:id(.:format)      admin/stats#show
            PUT     /admin/stats/:id(.:format)      admin/stats#update
            DELETE  /admin/stats/:id(.:format)      admin/stats#destroy
```

And here my routes.rb file:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
 namespace :admin do resources :stats end
 namespace :admin do resources :users end
 root :to => 'welcome#index'
end
```

Now what puzzles me. Lets enter one data row via the interface. Assume stats is under models/ and not models/admin. I changed and moved the class, renamed the  table and changed the index method of the controller to this (to reflect the new model)

```
def index
 @admin_stats = Stat.all #was Admin::Stat.all

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @admin_stats }
 end
end
```

Why do I now see this error of a non existing method when visiting the same URL again localhost:3000/admin/stats/ ?

```
 NoMethodError in Admin/stats#index

 Showing [...]/sample_app/app/views/admin/stats/index.html.erb where line #16 raised:
 undefined method `stat_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe96d51a348>:0x007fe96d53a1e8>
 ...
 16:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', admin_stat %></td>
```

I did not touch any view file and the object is still called @admin_stats and the routes created via 'rake routes' are still the same as expected. Why is it breaking? (I found a solution for myself by simply having an admin model of each model that simply inherits the regular model and using Admin::Stat as object, but I still like to understand why this breaks)

Comment: Would you provide the content of your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: Of course:
   SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do  
     namespace :admin do resources :stats end  
     namespace :admin do resources :users end  
  root :to => 'welcome#index'

Comment: also added it to the question. can you reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: No, I haven't tried to reproduce, but I have a similar project to refer to. Your code looks good. Don't have a clue not.

Answer (score 1):

The rails scaffold command you ran generates the stat model which is namespaced under admin, i.e. Admin::Stat.

Rails uses this model name to generate the route names. So, when you changed your model to simply Stat and passed it to the link_to helper method,

```
link_to 'Show', admin_stat
```

The admin_stat is just the name of the variable and it doesn't matter here. The admin_stat is an object of the class Stat so it looks for stat_path.

If you want the `admin/stats` in the url then you need to modify the routes.rb to

```
    scope "/admin" do
      resources :stats
    end
```

Comment: I am not if I understand what you mean? admin_stat is still the name of the variable in the iterator scope. Are you saying its name is converted to the underscore naming convention + "_path" and its checking if this path is defined in the routes? I tried that and it doesn't make a difference.

Thanks for the initial feedback, still trying to understand why this won't work.

Comment: No, the name of the variable does not make a difference, rails uses the name of the Model, which is Stat in your case so it looks for stat_path. Hope that made this clearer...
As for the solution, are you saying that it still raised the same error when you added what I mentioned to the routes.rb file ?

Comment: scope "/admin" do ... end does work yes. but i also want my controllers/views in admin folder, how can I use "resources :stats" to reference a controller in a sub folder?